# Is this formula approximating the prime counting function useful?

Tags: number-theory, functions, prime-numbers, soft-question

I made this function to approximate the prime counting function, $\pi(x).$ However I wasn't able to plot very much of it because Desmos froze. At each prime, $f(x)$ is supposed to increase by one unit, therefore giving an exact formula for $\pi(x).$ From what I plotted I don't think it's exact, but it looked close. Here $p_n$ is the nth prime number.

[Desmos plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bfnpeoueby)

$$f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp{\bigg(-\prod_{k=2}^{\lfloor e^x\rfloor}} \frac{p_n-1}{\ln(k)} \bigg) $$

I have a few questions:

> Although $f(x)$ seems accurate for small values of $x$, it could fail as $x$ gets larger. Is this formula accurate as $x$ gets large?

> Not all accurate expressions are useful. How useful might this expression be?

Comment: I think you should code your formula evaluator and plotter in C++, D or some other speedily executed programming language.   That way you can get past the frozen point of Desmos.

Comment: As you say, not all accurate expressions are useful... this one technically requires you to know *all* of the primes in order to calculate $\pi(x)$, which isn't all that helpful.

Comment: @EricSnyder Riemann's explicit formula requires you to know the nontrivial zeros

Comment: That's similar, but not quite the same. Here, you must already know $\pi(x)$ in order to calculation $\pi(x)$, which is a circular calculation: your input requires you to know your output. With the Riemann explicit function, you need an input $\{\rho\}$ (the zeroes) to find output $\pi(x)$. Which isn't circular, but even so might be considered *somewhat* useless for finding $\pi(x)$, but its usefulness extends elsewhere. I don't know how rapidly your function converges, but it must converge before $p_n < \sqrt{x}$ to be better than the Eratosthenes-Legendre sieve, which is a low bar.